# Is stripe webhook reliable? Can i write my business logic after webhook validation

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using stripe checkout sessions to process payments in my application.I want to talk here about 2 different approaches of building the payment solution.

- Using stripe webhook to get the confirmation of the payment done using `checkout.session.completed` event. Validate stripe signature, retrieve orderId from metadata used to create checkout session and using this metadata to fullfill the order.
- Once the payment is completed, get back to application and call another api (internal api) for fullfillment of the order, we will send `{orderId:orderId}` as data for the fulfillment. Now using orderId, we will fetch the checkout session info from stripe and use metadata from session to fullfill the order. **We will get orderId (uuid) from success URL of checkout session.**

To all the people who are using stripe in their production application, how have you implemented your stripe payment and which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to fulfil the order based on webhook events. You can follow this tutorial for [details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).

You shouldn't reply on the success URL redirection. There are many things that  could cause the redirection to fail (i.e., network problem, your server is down).

Webhooks, on the other hand, are much more reliable. If the first delivery is unsuccessful, Stripe will continue to [retry](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#events-and-retries) up to 3 days. You can also use the webhook signature to verify and ensure that the event is actually sent from Stripe.

Comment: Do you think that webhooks are reliable?
what are the chances of transaction getting failed? the ration b/w failure and success transaction.
stripe doesn't provide the best way to handle fulfillment.
can we use metadata field to store related data and use that later on?